# side effect between isc-dhcp-client, network speed and lightdm

Tags: networking, lightdm, dhcp

I have 300 computers on running on 14.04 64bits Ubuntu, i use isc-dhcp-client to get ip and name from my dhcp server.

I encounter the classic problem with lightdm "your system is running in low-graphics mode" at startup, but it's not a driver problem, it's very strange and i spend a lot of time to try to fix that :

1) if my computers are not connected on network, i don't encounter the problem, lightdm starts.

2) if my computer are configured with statics addresses and connected, i don't encounter the problem, `lightdm` starts.

3) if my computer are configured with DHCP client and connected to a 1Gb network i don't encounter the problem, `lightdm` starts.

The pb happened when for a reason or an other (switch configuration, wire etc ...) the computer are connected on a 100Mb network. It seems that isc-dhcp-client take more time to get the address and `lightdm` (i don't understand why) display the low graphic message.

When I get the message if i switch to a new `tty`, after a while, i see the computer get the name and the address, so i can't do `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` and everything is fine.

Before installing the 14.04 we used 12.04 and we also had problems with computer connected to 100Mb network to get DHCP configuration, it was slower than those connected on 1Gb network, and impact user authentication. but that did not impact lightdm.

Is anyone have ever encounter the problem?

Anyone knows a way to fix the problem, accelerate isc-dhcp-client, configure lightdm to launch after isc-dhcp-client got the ip parameters etc...